# java new Date() is different from mysql DateTime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jpa

I instantiate a date object with

new Date(), which is the current system time.

But when I use jpa entitymanger to merge it to MySQL,
MySQL is showing a different time. by the way ,this is maven project.

for example, in java, the date is Wed Jun 03 06:51:38 EDT 2020
in MySQL is 2019-12-29 06:51:38 est

I notice the timezone is different, but the date quite different.

Could someone help me what is going on ?

code is like following:

```
Image image = new Image();
        image.setDate(new Date()); //current system time   
EntityManager em = EMFactory.getEMF().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();



        em.merge(image);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

then  I go to check MySQL, the row showing different time

for the reference , the context setting on db is :

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of code to show what your Entity looks like, and what the code looks like to persist to MySQL? There's not enough detail here to be able to reproduce the issue for anyone to help debug this.

Comment: The clock on your MySQL server is probably misconfigured.

Comment: I don’t think we have a chance to tell from the information you have rpovided. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The time zone probably isn’t different. It could be America/Toronto or America/New_York in both cases, for example. Those time zones use EST in December and EDT in June.

Comment: You should not be writing code that implicitly depends on default time zone of the client, server, or database. Explicitly specify your desired/expected time zone in your code. You likely are exchanging date-time  values as dumb strings rather than as smart objects. JPA and Hibernate have been updated to exchange modern *java.time* objects. We cannot further diagnose your problem because you neglected to provide full details and code. Edit your Question to provide more info. Voting to close this Question as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

please check and edit your mysql timezone config.

```
#my.cnf|my.ini
default-time_zone = 'your time zone'
```

and restart your mysql service.
or you could have a  provisional solution,execute sql:

```
show variables like "%time_zone%";
set global time_zone = 'your time zone';
flush privileges;
```